# String is not translating to a different language in Android Studio Java?

Tags: java, android, translation

I need to translate the string that is showing using 'Toast' in the Android application to the default language of the device.
I defined string resources in the res/string.xml file in English and added the attribute translatable="true" to the  tag.

Let's say an app is installed on a device whose default language is German. The app should show toast messages in German.

**Code in res/string.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Newsapp</string>
    <!-- notification strings -->
    <string name="see" translatable="true">see</string>
    <string name="news" translatable="true">news</string>
</resources>
```

**Code in Activity:**

```
String see = context.getString(R.string.see).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
String news = context.getString(R.string.news).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);

String str = see + " " + news;

Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: You need to provide German translations of these strings as well. Did you expect the system to automagically translate all text to German for you? [This is a good overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization).

Comment: Also: due to difference is languages it's a bad idea to construct messages like you did: You should have a resource for the string "see news" and any other string, not for individual parts. The primary reason is because grammar is different  between languages. In some languages the verb might not come first and if you hard-code that order, then the translation *can't* be done correctly via resources.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Could you write a method for providing German translation and how to translate German?

Comment: No, if you want German text in your application, someone will have to translate your text. There might be automated tools, but since localization needs a lot of context that isn't generally available in just the resources, those tools are far from perfect (i.e. they might be a good start to seed your resources, but if that's all you use, then your app will definitely look wrong in anything but the language you wrote).

Comment: As an example: "see" could be translated as "sehen" and "news" as "Nachrichten", but "sehen Nachrichten" is  at best gramatically wrong and pretty much garbage. The appropriate term (assuming this is meant as a menu item to see news, for example) would be "Nachrichten ansehen" or something like that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I can handle that, but I need the method to translate manually or automatically. If you know how I can fix the code I provided, please help.

Comment: Did you read the link in my first comment? It explains in *lots* of detail how to bring translated strings into your code. Besides the concatenating-messages issue, your code isn't wrong, it's just that you need additional files to provide the content for the other languages.

Answer (score 0):

For each new language, you have to create new specific values folder. So, if I take german for example, you need to create new folder "values-de" and create new file "strings.xml" inside "values-de" folder. New strings.xml file will look like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Newsapp</string>
    <!-- notification strings -->
    <string name="see" translatable="true">sehen</string>
    <string name="news" translatable="true">Nachricht</string>
</resources>
```

Then, if German language is currently selected on your phone, values-de/strings.xml will be used.